ansible with aws ssm, can not get s3 because proxy
i need to use a proxy for get a file from s3, when i try to connect to run an ansible code with ssm connection, ansible try to connect to my s3 bucket, but he can not it because he need a proxy, in debug ansible try to make this:
<i-0d4d6ca2d1cfff63d> EXEC: curl -o '/home/ssm-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1733759066.379009-976884-169232842011530/AnsiballZ_setup.py' 'https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/i-0d4d6ca2d1cfff63d//home/ssm-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1733759066.379009-976884-169232842011530/AnsiballZ_setup.py?X

it's the internal ansible code, my playbook not try to get s3, this is my playbook:
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
    ansible_connection: aws_ssm
    ansible_aws_ssm_bucket_name: my-bucket
    ssm_timeout: 60
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://myproxy:4444
    https_proxy: http://myproxy:4444
  tasks:
    - name: Execute echo command
      shell: echo test

so it's possible to send to ansible internal code the proxy for get the s3 curl ? or it's possible tu use ssm without a s3 bucket ?
thanks in advance.
